# Seeing ads on every website no matter where I visit on my android phone

Tags: chrome-for-android, stock-browser, ads

I don't know what I've installed to my android phone but something cause my phone to show ads on every page I visit.

It doesn't matter if I use Google Chrome or default android browser.
I try to uninstall every app I got suspicious but it did not helped.

Here is a few screenshots of the problem (Click for full size):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wy6U.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAxEt.png]

Comment: I don't see the problem. It looks like the website your going to is the cause for the ads.  If you truely believe your phone is infected with malware ( its not ) then restore the fun from the factory settings.

Comment: I see those ads even on my personel website. That are not regular ads. I don't want to reset my phone to the factory settings. Looking for a fix such us deleting/uninstalling or checking a file. Is it possible to get rid of this problem by editing a file?

Comment: If it is addware, it comes in via a program install, it is often identified in the whole program descriptions or in user comments at the play store. It is usually easily removable using the standard un-install methods for programs. Research your programs at the play store, go to settings apps and remove stuff. Use an app backup program like appmonster (or others) to ease re-install of legit programs without network downloads.

Comment: As a side note, remember all those permissions you agreed to, there is a lot of discussion about avoiding programs that you end up providing unnessisary permission to do things like , change your system (more complex than that) when the program needs no such permission to do what it does alone. It can also be that control of background data , and automated updates would be desired by the user, to reduce surprise changes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but, I am aware of the app permissions and how to track them. I guess I fixed the problem just by updating the Chrome app. Pls check the answer below. @Psycogeek

Answer (score 1):

After uninstalling nearly all the apps downloaded from Play Store (except a few like Twitter, Facebook etc.), I still had the issue.

I, then, tried to uninstall Google chrome which seems to be not allowed to do in normal ways (I guess it is one of the default apps of the phone).

Lastly, I found out that there is an update for the Chrome on the Play Store. I updated the app and surprisingly see that the problem is solved.

Have no idea what happened there and still suspicious about the problem but, seems like I succeed.

P.S. I will be grateful if someone explains what happened to my phone, technically. (Does updating Chrome change things for the default web browser? Because, I was having the same issue both in Chrome and default browser)

Answer (score 0):

If you restore the setting of your default android browser then problem will solve.Actually I was also suffering from this problem. Try it and I am definitely sure ,your android web browser will not longer to show you adds whether you browse on a official websites.It works.